# I can't access item in php associative array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I can't echo these things in my array when i use `print_r` this is what i see

```
Array ( [Name] => blank [score] => 88 )<br/>
Array ( [Name] => Jeehbs [score] => 32 )<br/>
Array ( [Name] => Jeehbs [score] => 20 )<br/>
Array ( [Name] => blank [score] => 9 )<br/>
Array ( [Name] => blank [score] => 5 )
```

and this is what i see when i use `var_dump`

```
array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "blank" ["score"]=> string(2) "88" }<br/>
array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "Jeehbs" ["score"]=> string(2) "32" }<br/>
array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(6) "Jeehbs" ["score"]=> string(2) "20" }<br/>
array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "blank" ["score"]=> string(1) "9" }<br/>
array(2) { ["Name"]=> string(5) "blank" ["score"]=> string(1) "5" }
```

here is the code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
     $name = $rows['Name'];
     $score = $rows['score'];
     print_r($row); 

     echo '<div class="name">'.$name.'</div><div class="score">'.$score.'</div>';
  }
```

Comment: why are you using `$rows` ?  use  `$name = $row['Name'];`

Comment: You declared `$row` while you are using `$rows`, remove the final 's'

Comment: omg i can't believe i over looked that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you made a typo, it's:

```
$name = $row['Name'];
$score = $row['Score'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `$row` but you are using `$rows`. Do as below :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
     $name = $row['Name'];
     $score = $row['score'];
     print_r($row); 

     echo '<div class="name">'.$name.'</div><div class="score">'.$score.'</div>';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In while loop you should use `$row` instead of `$rows`.

Additionally, if you want to print the array result neatly, you can add `echo "<pre>";` before the `print_r` like below:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($comments, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
     $name = $row['Name'];
     $score = $row['score'];
     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($row); 

     echo '<div class="name">'.$name.'</div><div class="score">'.$score.'</div>';
  }
```